# Random color generator in text with use of in ionic 3 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, text, colors, ionic3

home.html

**create a card and access to json to values And data**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let shayari of shayar_list">
    <div class="card-title" [ngStyle]="{'color':shayari.color{{shayari.title}}</div>
</ion-card>
```

.ts

**create a json and access to math.random function calling**

```
this.shayar_list = [{
  title: 'Love Shayari',
  color : this.getRandomColor(),
]}
```

**create a ramdom color generator  function**

```
getRandomColor()
  {
      var color = "#";
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          var part = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
          color += (part.length > 1) ? part : "0" + part;
      }
      return color;
  }
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  shayar_list = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.shayar_list = [{
      title: 'Love Shayari',
      color : this.getRandomColor(),
    }];
  }
```

and function

```
  getRandomColor()
  {
      var color = "#";
      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      {
          var part = Math.round(Math.random() * 255).toString(16);
          color += (part.length > 1) ? part : "0" + part;
      }
      return color;
  }
```

and template

```
  <ion-card *ngFor="let shayari of shayar_list">
      <div class="card-title" [ngStyle]="{'color':shayari.color}">
        {{shayari.title}}
      </div>
  </ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only issue with html format , change that to :

```
<div class="card-title" [ngStyle]="{'color':shayari.color}">
   {{shayari.title}}
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-random-color)**